# Convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n^3-n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does this infinite series converge or diverge?

$$\sum\frac{1}{n^3-n^2} $$

I've tried every test I can think of but I can't figure it out. Is there a series greater than this that is convergent or a series smaller that is divergent? Or some other quality about this series that I am overlooking?

Please don't tell me to use the integral test, even if that method works.

Comment: for $n$ large enough you have $n^3-n^2>\frac{1}{2}n^3$

Comment: Note that $\left(\dfrac{1}{n^3-n^2}\right)_{n \in \mathbb N}\sim _{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: "convergance" in the title should be "convergence".

Comment: @FaheemMitha fixed. Presumably that mistake was on purpose because "Convergence of an infinite series" already exists.

Answer (score 7):

$0\le \frac{1}{n^3-n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2(n-1)}<\frac {1}{n^2}$ (for all $n>10434666$).

Comment: Why that extra condition ? n > 10434666

Comment: It's an upper bound, jokingly set way to high, probably.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can sum the series explicitly.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-n^2}
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\right)
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)\\
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
= 1 - (\zeta(2) - 1)
= 2 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

For large value of n, the factor behave like 1/n*3, hence by p test it is convergent